# Without xml possible on change method in openerp

Tags: odoo

```
def onchange_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, context=None):
    res = {}
    if partner_id:
        obj = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, partner_id)
        res['field1'] = obj.field1
        res['field2'] = obj.field2
        res['field3'] = 'Hello' # this field type must be char or if not then give 
        #value accordingly, its just to prove you that values are filled on onchange.
    return {'value': res}
```

---

```
def onchange_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, context=None):
```

but i am not write "onchange_partner" because it using without xml how it

Comment: Please format your code. It's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to write onchange method.

**Old Api :**

in *model.py*

```
def myonchange(self,cr,uid,ids,field_name,context=None):
    ...
    ...
    ... 
    return {'value':{'field': 'value'}}
```

in model_view.xml

```
<field name="field_name" on_change="myonchange(field_name)"/>
```

if you are using old api you need to add onchange attribute on field in xml view.

**New Api :**

```
@api.onchange('field_name')
def my_onchange(self):
      self.field_name = 'Value'  # to set filed value
```

in new API you need to add decorator which trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is changed in the form.